# Simulate a webpage feedback button

Tags: delphi, feedback

I like to place a feedback button on may main (MDIParent) form that simulates those in webpages.

Like it to grow when the mouse goes over it. Just like the web.
The form with questions and the send of the data, I really don't need it, just the visual stuff.

Is there any such component ?.
I don't think it's difficult to do, but if it already exist it will same me some time.

Thanks

Comment: Could you post a link to some page having that feedback button ? I'm not 100% sure what you mean...

Comment: @TLama The question is not about what it looks like, it's just about how to display a floating panel when the mouse moves over another element

Comment: @Juan, so then I probably missed the part with *grow when the mouse goes over it* because that sounds to me like some sort of animation.

Comment: It really helps when asking questions is you include the specific Delphi version you're using, so people don't have to try to remember or go look up your old questions to find out. Adding Delphi 7 tag.

Comment: That's most helpful when the answer actually depends on the Delphi version, @Ken. Unless you have an answer that's only valid for certain versions, I don't think you need to make the question overly specific. (So it's just as well you didn't follow through in adding the tag.) And even then, you could just mention which versions your answer applies to, perhaps concluding with an alternative solution for other versions.

Comment: @Rob, the version of Delphi is helpful here. Later versions of Delphi provide the DoMouseEnter/DoMouseLeave events that can be overridden in a component, while earlier versions specifically require you to handle the *CM_MOUSE*` events instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make an animated slide panel you can use a code like follows:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FFeedbackBtn: TPanel;
    FFeedbackPanel: TPanel;
    procedure OnFeedbackBtnMouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
    procedure OnFeedbackPanelMouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FFeedbackBtn := TPanel.Create(Self);
  FFeedbackBtn.Parent := Self;
  FFeedbackBtn.Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akBottom];
  FFeedbackBtn.Caption := '';
  FFeedbackBtn.SetBounds(0, 0, 40, ClientHeight);
  FFeedbackBtn.OnMouseEnter := OnFeedbackBtnMouseEnter;

  FFeedbackPanel := TPanel.Create(Self);
  FFeedbackPanel.Parent := Self;
  FFeedbackPanel.Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akBottom];
  FFeedbackPanel.Caption := 'Feedback panel';
  FFeedbackPanel.Visible := False;
  FFeedbackPanel.SetBounds(0, 0, 250, ClientHeight);
  FFeedbackPanel.OnMouseLeave := OnFeedbackPanelMouseLeave;
end;

procedure TForm1.OnFeedbackBtnMouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AnimateWindow(FFeedbackPanel.Handle, 150, AW_ACTIVATE or AW_SLIDE or
    AW_HOR_POSITIVE);
end;

procedure TForm1.OnFeedbackPanelMouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AnimateWindow(FFeedbackPanel.Handle, 150, AW_HIDE or AW_SLIDE or
    AW_HOR_NEGATIVE);
end;

end.
```

***Update:***

Here's another version of the above, now with a vertical text like a *typical feedback button* has, rendered on a paint box stretched on the *button* panel:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FFeedbackBtn: TPanel;
    FFeedbackBtnOverlay: TPaintBox;
    FFeedbackPanel: TPanel;
    procedure OnFeedbackBtnMouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
    procedure OnFeedbackPanelMouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
    procedure OnFeedbackBtnOverlayPaint(Sender: TObject);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FFeedbackBtn := TPanel.Create(Self);
  FFeedbackBtn.Parent := Self;
  FFeedbackBtn.Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akBottom];
  FFeedbackBtn.Caption := '';
  FFeedbackBtn.Color := $0000B3FF;
  FFeedbackBtn.ParentBackground := False;
  FFeedbackBtn.SetBounds(0, 0, 40, ClientHeight);

  FFeedbackBtnOverlay := TPaintBox.Create(Self);
  FFeedbackBtnOverlay.Parent := FFeedbackBtn;
  FFeedbackBtnOverlay.Align := alClient;
  FFeedbackBtnOverlay.OnPaint := OnFeedbackBtnOverlayPaint;
  FFeedbackBtnOverlay.OnMouseEnter := OnFeedbackBtnMouseEnter;

  FFeedbackPanel := TPanel.Create(Self);
  FFeedbackPanel.Parent := Self;
  FFeedbackPanel.Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akBottom];
  FFeedbackPanel.Caption := 'Feedback panel';
  FFeedbackPanel.Color := $0000F9FF;
  FFeedbackPanel.ParentBackground := False;
  FFeedbackPanel.Visible := False;
  FFeedbackPanel.SetBounds(0, 0, 250, ClientHeight);
  FFeedbackPanel.OnMouseLeave := OnFeedbackPanelMouseLeave;
end;

procedure TForm1.OnFeedbackBtnMouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AnimateWindow(FFeedbackPanel.Handle, 150, AW_ACTIVATE or AW_SLIDE or
    AW_HOR_POSITIVE);
end;

procedure TForm1.OnFeedbackPanelMouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AnimateWindow(FFeedbackPanel.Handle, 150, AW_HIDE or AW_SLIDE or
    AW_HOR_NEGATIVE);
end;

procedure TForm1.OnFeedbackBtnOverlayPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  S: string;
  X, Y: Integer;
begin
  S := 'Feedback...';
  with FFeedbackBtnOverlay do
  begin
    Canvas.Brush.Color := $0000B3FF;
    Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);
    Canvas.Font.Orientation := 900;
    X := (ClientWidth - Canvas.TextHeight(S)) div 2;
    Y := ClientHeight - (ClientHeight - Canvas.TextWidth(S)) div 2;
    Canvas.TextOut(X, Y, S);
  end;
end;

end.
```

And the result:

[image: Result]

You should also implement some logic to prevent user to hide the feedback panel when will actually filling the fields, but it's a natural weakness of such kind of a feedback form.

Comment: Yes. Did know about the AnimateWindow. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome! But it was just a guess. I'll extend this answer and try to add a gif with the animation effect (if I get the right applications for doing this).